# Facebook API - Business Manager как получить инфу без accessToken?

Tags: facebook, facebook-api, facebook-graph-api

Всем привет!

Есть сайт такой
https://checkbm.ru

Вот там можно указать ID своего БМа и получить инфу по нему. Имя, лимит,бан или нет.

Как это реализовывается?

Искал по документации - там везде  требует ключ доступа, а на том сайте ключ указывать не нужно...

Comment: По какому методу АПИ запрашиваешь инфу? Токен доступая получил с кода страницы FB

Answer (score 0):

Ключ доступа даётся всему приложению, он указывается при запросе от самого приложения, пользователю этот ключ знать вообще нельзя, он секретный. При постановке запроса к API FB вы указываете этот ключ и система фейсбука возвращает Вам данные.

На самом деле, извините, весьма глупый вопрос.

API facebook тут: https://developers.facebook.com/docs?locale=ru_RU

Comment: В том и дело, что я ключ свой не вписываю на тот сайт, а информацию о моём БМ - сайт получает. Вы не поняли вопроса или я так его задал что вы не поняли

Comment: Что такое ключи, где их брать и как использовать - я знаю. Но на том сайте ключ указывать не нужно, а информацию получить можно. Вот и вопрос - как они достают информацию по моим БМам которые я указываю, я просто ИД даю - а они мне столько информации

Comment: @user190134 нет это вы не поняли. Ключ даётся приложению и это приложение по другую сторону сайта, зачем пользователю то ключ вводить.

Comment: без ключа вы не получите информацию по АПИ. А тот сайт который я указал - без ключа информацию получает, как? Вот пример из документации
https://graph.facebook.com/412431279331122

Без ключа - информацю не покажет. А на тот сайт просто ИД вставляйте и получаете инфу

Comment: @user190134 ОН ПОЛУЧАЕТ ПО КЛЮЧУ!!! Просто попытайтесь понять!!!